# To generate multiple rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

on clicking the button i need my table to be added with multiple rows at once that consists of multiple columns.....the code is built by using java Script....i am using the insertcell() method to insert an empty cell in my table.....when i click the button and add a row there is been only a single row added at a time.....i want multiple rows (eg...7 rows) with the same number of columns to be shown by clicking that button only once....

how can i make the last row of the table (i mean if i add 7 rows in the table at once)...i need the 7th row border bottom to be solid and that gets repeated to every 7th border bottom..... in the above program......and also can i get some ideas of using rowspan and colspan in the above program

```js
function display(){ 

 var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow();  

   var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'time' name= 'time'  required> </td></tr><tr></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='70px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oraltype'  name= 'oraltype' required></td></tr><tr></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='55px';
   
   newCell= rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'oralamt' name= 'oralamt'  required></td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='75px';
   
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oralcommence'  name= 'oralcommence'  required></td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='65px';
      newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
      
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr><tr></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='50px';

   }
```

```css
 
#myTable1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    }
#myTable1 th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: black;
    width : 190px;
}

.table-fixed{
 
}
  #myTable1 .tbody1{
    height:150px;
    overflow-y:auto;
 }
 #myTable1 thead,.tbody1{
  
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1200px; align:left;" id="myTable1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan = '2' style="width:130px;">Date Comm.</th>
        <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Drug</th>
        <th  rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Dosage</th>
        <th  rowspan='2'style="width:130px;">Route Of Admin</th>
         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody1">

   
    </tbody>
     <tr id="hiderow">
      <td><button onclick="display()"></button></td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will create 10 rows. I have updated id for 1st field (time `id = 'time_" + i + "'`) to give it a unique id. You may choose to provide unique id's for each field so that you can read the values from JS.

```
function display() {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow();

        var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'time_" + i + "' name= 'time'  required> </td></tr><tr></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '70px';

        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oraltype'  name= 'oraltype' required></td></tr><tr></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '55px';

        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'oralamt' name= 'oralamt'  required></td></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '75px';


        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oralcommence'  name= 'oralcommence'  required></td></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '65px';
        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();

        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr><tr></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '50px';
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i make the last row of the table (i mean if i add 7 rows in the table at once)...i need the 7th row border bottom to be solid and that gets repeated to every 7th border bottom..... in the above program......and also can i get some ideas of using rowspan and colspan in the above program

Answer (score 0):

Would this usage of a loop be of any use to you? Whenever you call the function display() you want to feed it the number of rows your want to create.

```
function display(timesToLoop) {

    var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow();

    for (i = 0; i < timesToLoop; i++) {
        var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'time' name= 'time'  required> </td></tr><tr></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '70px';

        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oraltype'  name= 'oraltype' required></td></tr><tr></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '55px';

        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'oralamt' name= 'oralamt'  required></td></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '75px';


        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oralcommence'  name= 'oralcommence'  required></td></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '65px';
        newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();

        newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr><tr></tr>";
        newCell.style.width = '50px';

    }

}
```

This is untested Js, so it might need a slight adjustment here and there :)

You can find out more about the usage of `for` loops on [this article here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_for_loop.htm)! You can also find out more about function parameters [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add two Rows  -

```
var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length); 
var rowsAddNext = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length + 1); 

.............. // your code of adding cell into rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the snippet below or this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/NvObQM)**.

You can choose how many rows you want to add in the select menu next to the add button:

```js
function display() {
  var tableRef = document
    .getElementById("myTable1")
    .getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

  var numRows = document.getElementById('numRows').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow();
    var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    addRows(newCell, rowsAdd);
  }
}

function removeRows() {
  document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML = '';
}


function addRows(newCell, rowsAdd) {
  newCell.innerHTML =
    "<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'time' name= 'time'  required> </td></tr><tr></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = "70px";

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML =
    "<tr><td><input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oraltype'  name= 'oraltype' required></td></tr><tr></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = "55px";

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML =
    "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'oralamt' name= 'oralamt'  required></td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = "75px";

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML =
    "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oralcommence'  name= 'oralcommence'  required></td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = "65px";
  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();

  newCell.innerHTML =
    "<tr><td><i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr><tr></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = "50px";
}
```

```css
#myTable1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#myTable1 th {
  background-color: #009999;
  color: black;
  width: 190px;
}

.table-fixed {}

#myTable1 .tbody1 {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#myTable1 thead,
.tbody1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1200px; align:left;" id="myTable1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Date Comm.</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Drug</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Dosage</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Route Of Admin</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:50px;">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody1" id='tbody'>


  </tbody>
  <tr id="hiderow">
    <td>
      <select id="numRows"> 
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
      </select>
      <button onclick="display()">Add row(s)</button>

      <button onclick="removeRows()">Remove all rows </button>

    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You want like below example :

```js
$(document).ready(function display(){
 
  
  
  
  $('#add').click(function(){
  var row_c = $('#row_count').val();
  var row = "<tr> <td ><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> </tr>";
  
  for(var i=0;i < row_c ;i++){
  
  $('#myTable1').find('thead').append(row);
  }  
  })
})
```

```css
#myTable1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
   
 }
  tr{
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
#myTable1 th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: black;
    width : 190px;
}

.table-fixed{
 
}
  #myTable1 .tbody1{
    height:150px;
    overflow-y:auto;
 }
 #myTable1 thead,.tbody1{
  
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed table-hover table-condensed" border='1' id="myTable1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan = '2' >Date Comm.</th>
        <th rowspan='2' >Drug</th>
        <th  rowspan='2' >Dosage</th>
        <th  rowspan='2'>Route Of Admin</th>
         <th  rowspan='2' >Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody1">

   
    </tbody>
     <tr id="hiderow">
      <td>
        <input type='text' id='row_count'/><button id='add'>Add Row</button></td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
```

Comment: how can i make the last row of the table (i mean if i add 7 rows in the table at once)...i need the 7th row border bottom to be solid and that gets repeated to every 7th border bottom..... in the above program......and also can i get some ideas of using rowspan and colspan in the above program